# Using regex match from list to replace string with match

Tags: python, regex

I have 2 lists and would like to have matches from list_2 replace the entire string in list_1.

```
list_1
0   Univ Miami, Sch Med, Miami Project Cure Paralysis
1   Sch Med, Dept Neurol Chicago  Surg, 
2   Univ London, Sch Med, Dept Physiol & Biophys


list_2
0 New York
1 Chicago
2 London
3 Miami
...
```

Using something like `list_1.replace('(?i)(Miami)', 'test', regex = True)` I can only replace 'Miami' with 'test' but can not use list_2 as input pattern nor replace the entire string with the match.

What I would like to get as a result is:

```
list_1
0   Miami
1   Chicago
2   London
```

I hope that makes sense,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand the question. So, you want to replace every value in `list_1` by matching every value in `list_2` with `'test'`? But, the expected result shows only the matching words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regular expression to match and replace](/q/72277683/90527)

Comment: Hi @NaufalHilmiaji, I would like to replace all the string in list_1 if there is a regex match with any value in list_2

Comment: so:
1. How to use list_2 as an input in the regex function instead of a specific string like 'Miami'
2. How to replace the entire string in list_1 if any subpart of it matches the regex function

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), rather than leaving [comments](/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Please consult the [help] articles, especially "[ask]" and on providing a [mcve]. See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions for this.

Taking back your example

```
list_1 = ["Univ Miami, Sch Med, Miami Project Cure Paralysis",
"Sch Med, Dept Neurol Chicago  Surg,",
"Univ London, Sch Med, Dept Physiol & Biophys"]

list_2 = ["New York", "Chicago", "London", "Miami"]
```

You can define a function, `find_city`, that checks if a city name is present in your titles (`list_1`), and return the city name if it is found:

```
def find_city(title, list_cities):
    title_lower = title.lower()
    for city in list_cities:
        if city.lower() in title_lower:
            return city
```

Things to note:

- the use of the `in` operator to check if a string is contained in another; much simpler than using regular expressions.
- we are putting everything in lowercase (title and city names) before performing the search.

Finally you can use a list comprehension to build your desired output:

```
list_3 = [find_city(title, list_2) for title in list_1]
print(list_3)
>>> ['Miami', 'Chicago', 'London']
```